# Inject template from ngRoute into Directive AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive, ngroute, route-provider

Is it possible to inject (or maybe **merge** will be better word) a a template from ngRoute into the template in directive?

Let's explain in example:

There is a config with ngRoute

```
angular.module('dynamic-menu').config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('#', {
        controller: 'MainController',
        template: '<p>Main Page</p>'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('#/productReturn/', {
        controller: 'ProductReturnController',
        template: '<p>Product Return Page</p>'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('#/demand/', {
        controller: 'DemandController',
        template: '<p>Demand Page</p>'
    });
}]);
```

> I don't know that we need a controller to do sth?

And the directive:

```
angular.module('dynamic-menu').directive('menuTemplate', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var template = {
                'searcher': "<nav class=\"navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top\" role=\"navigation\" id=\"nav-bar\">"
                          + "<div class=\"container-fluid\">"
                              + "<div class=\"navbar-header\">"
                                  + "<span class=\"navbar-brand\" > INSERT TEMPLATE HERE </span>"
                              + "</div>"
                          + "</div> <!-- /.container-fluid -->"
                       + "</nav>",
                'main' : (...) <- not important
            }; //var template END

            var templateObj;
            if (attrs.templateName) {
                templateObj = $compile(template[attrs.templateName])(scope);
            }
            else {
                templateObj = $compile(template['main'])(scope);
            }
            element.append(templateObj);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Here is the line in the directive where I want to paste the template:

```
"<span class=\"navbar-brand\" > INSERT TEMPLATE HERE (for. ex. <p>Product Return Page</p>) </span>"
```

And in the HTML

```
<menu-template template-name="searcher"></menu-template>
```

Is it possible?

Or maybe - how to pass the value in the Controller into the directive without ng-view?

```
angular.module('dynamic-menu').controller('ProductReturnController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.header = "PROOODDUUUCCCTTT REEETUUURRRNNN TTTITTTTLEEEEE";
}]);
```

**UPDATE:**

I have a few pages, for. ex. in `page1` I will use my `<menu-template template-name="main"></menu-template>`

and  `page2` `page3` `page4` - inside these pages, I will use my `<menu-template template-name="searcher"></menu-template>`

Answer (score 0):

If your route consist of only the `menuTemplate` directive (as it seems to be), then just include that directive in the template:

```
template: '<menu-template template-name="search">SOME TEMPLATE FOR SEARCH</menu-template>'
```

Then make the directive transclude its contents. And, there is no need to manually `$compile` (although you can) - you can just define this in the directive template:

```
var template = {
  search: "<nav class='navbar'>\
             etc...\
             <div ng-transclude></div>\
           </nav>",

  main: "..."
};

return {
  template: function(element, attrs){
    return template[attrs.templateName]; 
  },
  transclude: true,
  link: function(scope, element){
    // whatever else (other than the template) you might need here
  }
}
```

Comment: The thing is - that in the "searcher" template there will be few subpages and each subpage will have an unique template, which I want to dipslay

Comment: @karolinka, I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "subpage" here... edit your question with examples of what you want to achieve. Your question is framed as "how to do X", but underlying it might be the desire to achieve "Y" - let's focus on "Y" (see [XY questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: I made an update, maybe now it will be more clean. Look into whole code, because I made corrections in almost all `code` sections

Comment: @karolinka, what is "page"? Is it a route? And if so, can you specify the `template-name="searcher"` accordingly.

Comment: Yes, page is a route. `template-name="searcher"` is inside the directive, can you tell me what I need to tell you ? Sorry, but I'm lost :(